# Is there a way to fix this django stripe integration error?

Tags: django, stripe-payments, payment

We are integrating stripe for as US stripe account.
There is no connection to India but we are getting this error... Instead of the payment URL:

> Request req_OuSWvylGF8wZDi: As per Indian regulations, only registered Indian businesses (i.e. sole proprietorships, limited liability partnerships and companies, but not individuals) can accept international payments.

More info here: [Stripe Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/)

We tried integrating stripe, and backend Django for US based company. But we keep on getting Indian regulations errors. We don't know how. There is no relation to India.

Comment: This type of error usually means that the Stripe account making the API request is in India. You can check the country of your account on this page: https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/account

Comment: I googled the error message and got this: https://stripe.com/docs/india-accept-international-payments